# how to get a double value out of a string in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of strings to be shown in a dropdown.i.e.

```
String selectedLeverage = '1 : 100';
final leverageSelected = TextEditingController();
List<String> leverage = [
     "1 : 1",
     "1 : 2",
     "1 : 5",
     "1 : 10",
     "1 : 50",
     "1 : 100",
     "1 : 200",
     "1 : 500",
     "1 : 800",
     "1 : 1000",
     "1 : 2000",
     "1 : 3000",
     ];
```

**What I want:**
I want to extract the last element of the string as a double value when any particular value is selected from the dropdown to do calculations in the future. (e.g. In case, the user chose 1:100 from the dropdown, I want to have 100 as a double out of the string "1:100" which I am getting from the list leverage )

**What I am doing:**

```
  double leverage = double.parse('$selectedLeverage.split(" ")[2]');
  print(leverage); // i am expecting to get a doble value here =100.0 but this is giving me 1.0
```

**Here**

```
   selectedLeverage.split(" ")
```

is converting the the string "1:100" in to a list ["1",":","100"]
and I am trying to convert "100" to double 100.0 by using

```
   double.parse('$selectedLeverage.split(" ")[2]')
```

**I don't know where I am doing wrong.**

Comment: instead of `List<String> leverage = [` cannot you have `List<int> leverage = [` (or `List<double>`)?

Comment: What's your output?

Comment: Just tried the code myself and it turns out, it is converting your value to `int` rather than `double` 
Even if you add `.00` to your values it would neglect those 0s since they don't matter.

Comment: @ASADHAMEED Did you test the code in DartPad? If so, DartPad appears to ignore toDouble() and double.parse. The code (@TSR's) works ok in a Flutter/Dart program in VSCode dedugger. Think this is to do with the underlying Javascript. I raised an issue to query this.

Comment: @pskink I have to show 1: 100 in the drop-down. there is a : sign in between 1 and 100 that's why I am using string .

Answer (score 1):

Add the curly brackets

```
double.parse('${selectedLeverage.split(" ")[2]}')
```

Or just remove quotes

```
double.parse(selectedLeverage.split(" ")[2])
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer. But I'd prefer to use `selectedLeverage.split(" ").last` instead of hardcoded index 2. It would be more consistent with described logic.

Comment: I tried both removing {} as well as adding .last but this is giving the same result

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out the mistake myself everything was right but the problem was in the dropdown. The value of selected leverage wasn't changing on selecting different leverage value